# Asus G550 no sound

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa

I have no sound coming from the notebook (on windows it works), if I plug in a headset it does work flawlessly.

Reading up on the issue I couldn't find any working solution. But seen people love to see ALSA info, so here it is: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=cfe46c697339f6aec2ce1b9919b5ded493051b58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From alsa-info, your internal soundcard is the second one, HDMI output being the first: Install and run "pavucontrol" (pulse audio volume control) . Launch it from multimedia menu, go to the "output devices" tab, and click the green "define as alternative" button that is near the second  soundcard (HDA Intel PCH ).

If it still doesn't work, look also "configuration" tab and change profile.

Some people here have reported problems with dual boot and windows8: if affected, you have to completely switch off computer from Windows 8 and/or disable "fast boot" in Windows8.

Comment: Sadly no, Windows fast boot is disabled. Pavucontrol shows sound output, but no combination makes the sound actually come out of the speakers :(

Comment: Run `alsamixer` in a terminal , press F6 to select non hdmi sound card, and look if "speaker" fader is muted or low level (use arrow keys to move thru fader , spacebar to mute/unmute). Change also "automute" switch : test in "disable" mode

Comment: you can try to disable pulseaudio for test with 2 commands: `echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf` then `pulseaudio -k` . Relaunch  audio apps, they  will use only Alsa , check if it is better

Comment: Thanks for the continous help, I accept yours, because suddenly (after second restart the sound works. I hope it will continue to work though.

Comment: Thanks, may be you really shutdown and stop computer from windows  ?

Comment: Possible, but interestingly enough Fast boot is turned off. :)